# Flutter Firebase google signin release signing key problem

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin, fingerprint

i have flutter app wtih firebase auth.
I have signing key for release and config like this in gradle.build

```
signingConfigs {
   release {
       keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
       keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
       storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
       storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
   }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        // signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

i have added SHA1 and SHA256 fingerprints to firebase by generating them by running:
`keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\...\assets\key.jks" -alias key -storepass ...pass... -keypass ...pass...`

when i am building fith flutter run --release all works fine hwoever when i run in debug mode i am not able to signin with google untill i add SHA's for `\.android\debug.keystore`

(to make sure release signing key is used i added if to build.gradle

```
 if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        println "Signing with key.properties"
    } else {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        println "Signing with debug keys"
    }
```

and it takes release right one)

any ideas why? Does in debug mode takes debug keys by default? from my point of view it should use release key anyway...

p.s. yes i am replacing google-services.json with flutter clean

Answer (score 0):

Just like you added a `release` section under `signingConfigs` you need to do same for `debug` and specify the same details as mentioned in the `release` ones.

Comment: Maybe i did not explain my self good enough. Google signin works even without specifying debug config BUT ONLY when i add debug SHA into Firebase - my question is HOW? WHY? It signs DEV build with RELEASE key but requires debug SHA????